# Python returns nothing

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a strange issue. When I run the code below and the image isn't present the code should return "None" but for some reason nothing is printed.

PS: When I run this code in a virtual machine everything works fine and None is returned.

```
    try:
       inv_settings = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("settings.png", confidence=0.99)
    except Exception:
       pass
```

EDIT:

```
import pyautogui

settings = not None
while settings is not None:
    try:
        inv_settings = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("settings.png", confidence=0.99)
        print(inv_settings)
    except Exception:
        pass

print("finished")
```

Comment: an exception happened and you just suppressed it... in the `except Exception as e:` part, put `print(repr(e))`. That way you can check the error.

Comment: Also, if you want to return `None`, don't `print` out anything. Printing is completely different from returning.

Comment: @GeeTransit This is printed: ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the image (highest confidence = 0.824)')

Comment: Well, it does still return None. Here, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Avoid `except Exception: pass` constructs in the future. It greatly hinders debugging of your code. In fact it has been called the [most diabolical python antipattern](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/).

Comment: But why does my virtual machine just returns None? The code is exact the same.

Comment: Some interpreters print out everything, including a `None` return value. The default Python interpreter doesn't do that so you can focus on the important things.

Comment: @GeeTransit, Yes it seems to be the interpreter, any idea which one I need to download? I just downloaded the latest version but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Most interpreters don't print out a `None`, but you can print it out manually by putting `print(expression)`. I don't know any interpreters that print out everything other than some simple REPLs that I've made myself :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it so it returns `None` no matter what, just remove the `print`.

```py
def find():
    try:
        inv_settings = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("settings.png", confidence=0.99)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

The Python interpreter doesn't print out `None` as it means there isn't anything useful to show, but you can still print out the actual return value.

```py
>>> find()
>>> # nothing was printed out because find() returned None
>>> print(find())
None
>>>
```

EDIT: Also, you reeeeally shouldn't suppress all exceptions as this may block an actual error in your code. In this case, you should make it return `True` if it was found and `False` if not. Otherwise, it is just wasting time and energy to give a result that doesn't tell you anything.

EDIT2: Looks like you've updated the question with the full code. I'll supply you with the updated code and comments.

```py
# all imports at the top :)
import pyautogui

# set `location` to None
location = None

# i'm assuming you want to keep locating until you find it so keep on
# checking until location isn't None anymore
while location is None:

    # i've checked the documentation and it seems that 
    # pyautogui.locateOnScreen either returns the location in
    # a named tuple `Box(left, top, width, height)` or it
    # raises pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException

    # here we try to get the location of "settings.png" on our screen
    try:
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("settings.png", confidence=0.99)

    # we catch the exception if it can't find it. note we don't catch
    # all exceptions as it might hide other problems.
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        pass

print("finished")
```

Comment: I've made an edit to my post. The code I posted is just a part of a bigger code and the print is just a test because I need "None" returned to get out of a while loop which isn't happening

Comment: @ScoobyDuh I've edited my answer with your update. Hopefully it works :)